# Does Java have an equivalent to .NET resource (.resx) files for localization?

Tags: java, .net, localization, internationalization, globalization

Does Java have an equivalent to .NET resource (.resx) files for localization?

In .NET, you can define resources as key-value pairs within a standard XML document.

The resource files are named according to the culture. For example:

> myresources.resx
>
> myresources.en-us.resx
>
> myresources.fr-fr.resx
>
> myresources.de-de.resx

Is there an equivalent in Java? Are the similar naming conventions used for files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Java equivalent is called [`ResourceBundle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html). Resource Bundle are java properties file (with a `.properties` file extension that can be accessed using **java.util.ResourceBundle** class) that contains locale-specific data.

From your example,

```
myresources.resx
myresources.en-us.resx
myresources.fr-fr.resx
myresources.de-de.resx
```

Is equivalent to (in java)

```
myresources.properties
myresources_en_US.properties
myresources_fr_FR.properties
myresources_de_DE.properties
```

For Technical data on `ResourceBundle` check this Oracle article here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/concept.html

Comment: Even Wikipedia has something to say: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_resource_bundle

Comment: I believe they are underscore separated, and country code is capitalized - e.g., myresources_en_US.properties

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is ResourceBundles in Java. Here is a nice [link](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/ResourceBundles/)

Answer (score 0):

ResourceBundles should be the Java equivalent.
Refer to http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html